# Javascript regex to check for error tags

Tags: javascript, json, regex

I need to write a regex that will tell me if any back-end framework that I'm working with is throwing an error and then store those errors in an array for retrieval if necessary.

The issue is, they use different tags for errors. Tags are as follows:

`{{error}}`, `<<error>>`, `[[error]]`, and `<{:error:}>`

Usually, but not always, a set of braces will come after. Inside the braces will be a string; either an explanation of the error, or a JSON string containing more info about the error, like this:

```
<<error>> { Something has gone terribly wrong. }
<<error>> {
   {"some":"json"}
}
<{:error:}> { What went wrong? }
```

As of now, it's undergoing a specific check for each tag, which is rather inefficient, like this:

```
if ( string.indexOf('<<error>>') >= 0 )
  // Remove << and >> 
if ( string.indexOf('[[error]]') >= 0 )
  // Remove [[ and ]]
// So forth...
```

Then, I am left with a string like this:

```
error { Some description. }
```

or

```
error {
  {"some":"json"}
}
```

Which I need a regex to extract what's between the brackets. This was the regex I wrote, but it falls short on numerous things:

```
string.match('/error\s?\{([^\}]+)\}/gi');
```

As I said, this procedure is very inefficient and has issues.

First, it doesn't allow the braces `{}` after `error` to be optional. They should be optional.

Second, it does not allow JSON as the charset `[^}]` is not matched when JSON presents it's closing`}`. So I need some way of matching all characters in a set until the opening bracket of `error` is closed. Is this possible?

Comment: I'd fix the backend processing so the errors are uniformed. If not I think you could find the tags with `(?:\{\{|<<|\[\[|<\{:)error(?:\}\}|>>|\]\]|:\}>)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the comments on my first answer, I'd use this regular expression as a replace to convert the data into single-line json, the regex also removes comments. It removes newlines that do not start with  a properly labeled error. Multiline must be on.

- `(?:\/[\s\S*]*?\*\/|\/\/.*$|\s*^\s*(?!<<|{{|\[\[|<{:)))` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/mcS5na/4))
- or `(?:\s*^\s*(?!<<|{{|\[\[|<{:))` if there are never comments to remove

And then this to extract the error information, on the reformatted string, this regex to match.

`({{error}}|<<error>>|\[\[error\]\]|<{:error:}>)[ \t]*(?:(.*)}\s*$)?` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/6bZVRq/1)

---

I'll leave the other answer intact as I think it basically explains the problems that a person can encounter doing this.

Comment: I've gotten them consolidated to one tag `[[error]]` and all on one line, but I cannot get a regex to capture all errors into an array. https://jsfiddle.net/8e9Lfdjf/

Comment: @DanL A large part of the problem was that I forgot to account for {{ in the first regex. I just missed it somehow and coincidentally there wasn't any in my demo. **That's fixed.** It all appears to be working now. **Separately** You can write regexes much clearner in javascript if you don't derive them from a string , able to use single slashes. Finally you can use this to standardize_tags and avoid the loop `({{error}}|<<error>>|\[\[error\]\]|<{:error:}>)` replaced with `[[error]]`. Apologies, https://jsfiddle.net/8e9Lfdjf/5/

Answer (score 1):

Good question. Explained your problem, showed what you've tried, gave enough examples of input.

Regex, especially Javascript's limited implementation, is not ideal for parsing many languages and data objects. It can be difficult in this scenario to capture say 5. `.*` wants to go to 6 and `.*?` wants to go to 4.

```
{
{
{
}  // 5
}  // 5
}  // 6
```

**However, if your code is really indented like your examples (it may not be, that could be you making it readable)**, you should be able to use something like this `({{error}}|<<error>>|\[\[error\]\]|<{:error:}>)\s*(\s*{(.*?(?=$)|[\s\S]*?^)})?`, ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/829RFc/3))

What this is doing is

- capturing from `{` to `}` on the same line and if it can't, it proceeds to step 2 (alternation.
- everything between `{` and `}` as long as `}` starts the line.

If the `}` is always prefixed by a certain number of spaces, you can prefix the marked } with that number of spaces in the regex.

```
({{error}}|<<error>>|\[\[error\]\]|<{:error:}>)\s*(\s*{(.*?(?=$)|[\s\S]*?^)})?`
                                                                          ^
```

If the `}` is always prefixed by the same number of spaces as the opening error marker, you can do this

`([t ]*)({{error}}|<<error>>|\[\[error\]\]|<{:error:}>)(?:[ \t]*({(.*?(?=}$)|[\s\S]*?^\1)})?)` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/829RFc/4))

For this example, it's important to look at the full sample indent text. I demonstrate how it can go wrong.

If these won't work, you'll need a more code-oriented solution, but at the very least you can detect presence of errors with this

`({{error}}|<<error>>|\[\[error\]\]|<{:error:}>)`

. Chris85's simpler version is bad form, it could match `<<error]]` and any other combination, something he's probably aware of.

Comment: Thanks for the fluid answer and demo, but I have a question yet. It will not always be formatted, you're correct, sometimes no space will be present at all. I could not get this example working without whitespace, and I could not get it to display the JSON in the `Message` field.

Comment: @DanL forgot to tag you in last comment. Unsure if you saw it. Can you amend your post with an input you're having trouble with?

Comment: I've commented in this fiddle where I am having issues. If you see anything I'm doing that could be done more efficiently feel free to alter that as well. https://jsfiddle.net/3de9tLfz/

Comment: @DanL I broke the solution down into a separate answer, maybe it will help more. I poked at your fiddle a little bit, but didn't have a lot of time.

Comment: @Danl Also thank you for the fiddle. For putting in the effort.